# Ruta escaping special characters

Tags: ruta

I am working on a Ruta script to identify currency, but I am having troubles with special characters like dollar sign ($).

I tried with simple character:

```
W{REGEXP("(dollar|nzd|$)") -> MARK(EntityType)};
```

an escaping it:

PACKAGE uima.ruta.example;

```
W{REGEXP("(dollar|nzd|\$)") -> MARK(EntityType)};
```

In the first case my pattern is not recognized, in the second case my editor gives me an error.

What's is the correct way to identify special characters?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UIMA Ruta, the special characters are part of the default seed annotation `SPECIAL`. Your rule matches only on word tokens `W`; therefore it won't fire.

In case you want to match only on $ as special character, then you could limit the `SPECIAL` annotation with an `REGEXP` condition as you do for `W`:

```
// I spent $100.
SPECIAL{REGEXP("\\$"} -> Currency} NUM{-> Amount};
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yeah thanks, it definitely helps. I am trying to combine the 2, my initial script with W (usd|dollars|dollar) with your SPECIAL one so I can detect both, but I can't find the notation to have an OR condition between W and SPECIAL.
I tried many things around this one:

SPECIAL{REGEXP("\\$")} | W{REGEXP("(?i)(nzd|dollar|dollars)")} -> MARK(EntityType);

But none worked.

Comment: Try this one:
`((W{REGEXP("nzd|dollar|dollars|usd", true)} | SPECIAL{REGEXP("\\$")}) NUM){-> MARK(EntityType)};`
The difference here is just to make your string currency symbols case insensitive by adding a boolean to REGEXP condition.
Generally, I would rather put the string symbols into a wordlist and let Ruta find them.